# How to load from R. using name in android

Tags: java, android, image, drawable

i have a lot of images in my drawable folder and i want to put it in setImageDrawable()..
But i don't know how to get the image using the picture name..
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setImageResource()` and pass the `R.drawable.pic_name_here`.

---

Here's a typical example:

```
if (bonus <= 0) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.feed_points_off);
} else {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.feed_points_on);
}
```

or even

```
imageView.setImageResource(isFemale ? R.drawable.ic_female : R.drawable.ic_male);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
ViewObject.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name;
```

Comment: The 1st won't work since setImageDrawable expects a Drawable object

Comment: yes, you are right. I was having in mind the function he wrote in the question.